# MATLAB: Plotting double bottom x-axis

Tags: matlab, label, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot double bottom x-axis according to the figure after the jump:

[image]

It is a semilogx-plot in hours with additional specific ticks representing minutes, months and years. How do I create these additional ticks?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Victor May's approach to overlay a secondary axes, but this needs more tweaking to actually work.

First, let's recreate the basic plot:

```
clear, close
time = [1/60, 1, 24, 24*7, 24*30, 24*30*6, 24*365, 24*365*10];
r = [110, 90, 80, 75, 70, 65, 63, 60];

% plot the data
semilogx(time, r, 'o-')

% adjust ticks and format of primary axes
xlim([0.005 1e6])
ylim([0 140])
tick = 10 .^ (-2 : 6);
set(gca, 'XTick', tick)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', arrayfun(@num2str, tick, 'UniformOutput', false))
set(gca, 'XMinorTick', 'off')
set(gca, 'TickDir', 'out')
```

[image]

Overlaying a secondary axes only works properly if it has the same position, size, axis limits, and scale type as the primary, *and* if its background is transparent (otherwise the data become hidden):

```
% put matching secondary axes on top with transparent background
pos = get(gca, 'Position');
axes('Position', pos)
set(gca, 'Color', 'none')
xlim([0.005 1e6])
ylim([0 140])
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')
set(gca, 'XMinorTick', 'off')
set(gca, 'TickDir', 'out')
```

Giving it the proper ticks and tick labels

```
% adjust ticks
set(gca, 'YTick', [])
set(gca, 'XTick', time)
label = {'1 min', '1 hour', '24 hours', '1 week', '1 month', '6 months', '1 year', '10 years'};
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', label)
```

results in

[image]

– not really what we want.

With a trick we can let the ticks and tick labels of the secondary axes go inside...

```
% tinker with it
set(gca, 'XAxisLocation', 'top')
pos(4) = eps * pos(4);
set(gca, 'Position', pos)
```

[image]

...but that's still not really what we want.

---

A different strategy: Let's not overlay axes, but put the additional ticks in ourselves!

```
label = {'1 min', '1 hour', '24 hours', '1 week', '1 month', '6 months', '1 year', '10 years'};
line([time', time'], [0 2], 'Color', 'k')
text(time, 4 * ones(size(time)), label, 'Rotation', 90, 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle')
```

The result

[image]

is still not perfect, but useable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding another axes object to the plot and then setting the properties of its tick marks. Something like this:

```
close all
plot(1:10, 1:10)
set(gca,'XTick',[1:2:10])
haxes1 = gca;
set(haxes1, 'TickDir', 'out')
haxes1_pos = get(haxes1,'Position'); % store position of first axes
haxes2 = axes('Position',haxes1_pos);
set(gca, 'Color', 'none')
set(haxes2, 'YTick', [])
set(haxes2, 'XTickMode', 'manual');
set(haxes2, 'XTick', [ 0.1 0.8])
set(haxes2, 'TickDir', 'in')
```

In addition to the code in this example, you will have to edit the tick labels and axis range of the additional axes object. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/individual-axis-control.html#f1-16587) for reference on the XLim and XTickLabel properties which do that.

MATLAB doesn't currently support tick labels inside the axes. A 3rd party function that handles this can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41371-ticklabelinside/content/ticklabelinside.m).

Comment: One problem: this way you get ticks to the inside but not tick labels to the inside.

Comment: Also, in the end result the originally plotted data are invisible.

Comment: I've addressed both comments in my answer.